# Its is possible to remove OPTIONS request by client side only?

Tags: javascript, cors, fetch, axios

I had a debate with my coworker, he says that its possible to remove the options request (before POST, PUT etc..) without having to configure the max-age header at the response from the server.
this is possible? using XHR or fetch?

Comment: the OPTIONS call is made by the browser when it wants to and cannot be controlled by you, I've had the same debate. I suspect your calling an API and seeing these "extra" calls? I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**OPTIONS**: 
It is generally called as pre flight call. It will happen only if you are hitting *cross domain*.

**Cross domain** :

1. your client is running at abc.com and server is at xyz.com. Browser will treat it as cross domain call.
2. Even if you are hitting the same domain but the port varies. Browser will treat it as cross domain.

**To avoid preflight**:

Have your own simple http server, let it talk to xyz.com . Since we are hitting different domain from our server, browser will not make **OPTIONS** call.

If you need further help let me know.

Comment: So if my client and server are cors, there is no way to cancel the options request (without setting the max-age header) right?

Comment: Yeah there is no way to cancel it.

Comment: like I thought. but when I am using Rested / Postman, there is no option request, what is the explanation for that?

Comment: Generally browser will not allow us to consume cors req. We will get the response, but we can't use it. If we set access control header as * in the server response. Then it will allow. CORS mainly blocked by browser only, that is the reason you can able to hit from POSTMAN. 

POSTMAN is not exactly our client (i.e browser). I hope you got it. If need any thing , please let me know.